# If a single species disappears,

Tags: word-usage

> If a single species disappears, every other living creature could be affected.

Can I replace "a single" with "a single of" like: If a single of species disappers, ~ ?

Comment: No, you can't. Single is an adjective modifying species. There is no room for a preposition.

Comment: You mean even with a noun version of single can not be used, don't you?

Comment: If you wanted to use **of**, you would have to say something like:  **If a single member of a species disappears....** but this means something quite different and doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: @BEBYGONES  But *single* as a noun doesn't make sense here; because it doesn't mean "a single kind of".

Comment: Single as a noun has various common meanings: an unmarried person, a room with only enough space for one person, a short music recording, a single point scored in some sports, a one-way ticket, a $1 bill, a small shot of spirits, etc. Dictionaries say it can mean one of something, but that's really just the base from which the other meanings derive, rather than being a common usage in itself. Compare "double" or "hundred".

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure why you asked this question.

The basic form for indicating that an adjective modifies a noun is to place the modifying adjective immediately before the modified noun. English, unlike for example Latin, does not have a rich system of inflection to link modifying adjective and modified noun by number, gender, and case. There is no preposition involved in that basic form

> The little dog

is correct, whereas

> The little of dog

is not correct **at all**.

I do not want to get into a complete explication of the exceptions to this basic rule, but if a prepositional phrase acts as a modifier of a noun, the phrase precedes the article or follows the noun.

> Of a pale yellow hue, the apple

or

> The apple, of a pale yellow hue,

Now to get to your question specifically, “single” is an adjective (except in baseball lingo).

> A single of species

is as gross an error as “The little of dog.”

What is confusing is that the word “couple” is a noun that is sometimes used elliptically as though an adjective.

> A couple of little dogs

may well be shortened in speech or informal writing like texting to

> A couple little dogs

This may be the source of your confusion.

Comment: @BEBYGONE's comment suggests that they were intending the noun _single_; but that has no meaning that is relevant here.

Comment: @ColinFine Yes. You are correct. I must admit that I did not notice BEBBYGONE’s comment when I wrote my answer. Given that that comment lacks even a subject, I doubt it would have changed how I answered the original question. In fact, my initial reaction is that “single” used as a noun is usually better described as “single” being an adjective for an implied noun. I’d use “singleton” as the correct noun except in specific cases where the implied noun is absolutely clear, *e.g.*, “a meeting place for singles.”